# What is the best/idomatic way to iter and actions in Rust

Tags: loops, rust, iteration

Hello I have this piece of code :

```rust
let mut quotations: Vec<CreateQuotationArgs> = Vec::new();
let mut insert_documents = Vec::new();
while let bson::Bson::Document(document) = bson::to_bson(&quotations.pop()).unwrap() {
    insert_documents.push(document);
}
```

I would like to perform the same operation (putting quotation in a document BSON) but without using `pop()` method to keep `quotations` vector filled.

I know that I could use `map()` and `iter()` method but is that the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Best" is quite loaded. It's hard to answer that properly without broader context.

The following is equivalent to your original code (assuming you don't care about the order), but without removing items from `quotations`:

```
let quotations: Vec<CreateQuotationArgs> = Vec::new();
let mut insert_documents = Vec::new();

for quotation in &quotations {
    if let bson::Bson::Document(document) = bson::to_bson(quotation).unwrap() {
        insert_documents.push(document);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

A more idiomatic approach would be to not mutate any vectors and instead collect the results into a new one:

```
let quotations: Vec<CreateQuotationArgs> = Vec::new();

let insert_documents: Vec<_> = quotations
    .iter()
    .filter_map(|quotation| {
        if let bson::Bson::Document(document) = bson::to_bson(quotation).unwrap() {
            Some(document)
        } else {
            None
        }
    })
    .collect();
```

This isn't *exactly* the same because it will continue to parse items even after it comes across one that is not a `Bson::Document`. What's good about it though is that it avoids mutable variables.

Comment: It's not quite equivalent, since it (a) doesn't reverse the order of the items, while the original code does and (b) doesn't continue when the source vector is exhausted while the original code does. I don't think the original code has the intended behaviour, I'm just pointing out the differences. :)